# Facebook app : I'm getting different user id on new created faecbook app

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created 2 Facebook apps, one for the live site, the other one for the localhost site.

They works both, but when I login to the local i am getting different user id .

i am want all which user are login on local host.that user can able to login on live site it is possible ?

Comment: That is by design. With API v2.0, Facebook introduced app-scoped user ids - to better protect people’s privacy. You can only match those across different apps, if you have a business registered on Facebook and add both apps to it.

Comment: But that is probably not what you want. Instead of creating two different apps, create a _test app_ for the one you use on the live site. Those share the same app-scoped User ID namespace https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps